# Print multiple PDF files without showing Printer Dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to create a method in web application ASP.Net + C# to take as input parameters PDF file paths, then print all of it without showing Selection printer dialog, so it prints using default printer.

Comment: Do the PDF files reside on the client machine or on the server? By "method in web application" do you mean a method executed on the client machine or on the server? Is the printer connected to the client machine or to the server?

Comment: PDF is in server side and printer connected to client machine

Answer (score 3):

The best you can do is concatenate the PDF files into one file and then print it, showing the printer dialog once at the beginning of the process.  There are many commercial .NET PDF libraries that have this functionality.

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.  Here the code for doing it with DotImage

```
PdfDocument.Combine("Output.pdf", "doc1.pdf", "doc2.pdf", "doc3.pdf");
```

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/white-papers/building-pdf-documents-with-dotimage

Comment: The only possible way to print without a prompt from a browser is to make a browser extension/plugin.  It is a security problem to allow websites to print without user interaction.  If you have access to the user's printer from your web-server, you could print from the server side without a dialog.  However, they would need to set up their printer in your app beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

A web application cannot silently print to a client's printer. This will be a violation of the browser security model. Browsers and PDF browser plugins have to show a dialog box and prompt the user to allow printing.

Comment: so is there are any work around to do that using client printer from my web application

Comment: If your server is on the same LAN as the client (Intranet users), and your server can access the same printers -- then yes, the server can print to it without a dialog.  Usually, this would not be the case with the public Internet, but inside a company, it's possible.

Comment: If your users are open to using a Java applet, then this can be done. The applet could be made to select a printer on the client's side and then print to it. However, consider the implications of this. Imagine visiting some website and the web page suddenly printing to your printer without even notifying you. Also, how will your app determine which printer to print to - randomly selected or just the first one? This is why user intervention is necessary. Here is my Java applet article http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=195&t=A_Java_PDF_Web_Viewer_-_Powered_By_PDFOne_(for_Java_trade;)